# Large almost equilateral sets in finite-dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, discrete-geometry, metric-embeddings

Question: Does there exist a function $C:~(0,1)\to
(0,\infty)$  such that for each $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ every Banach space
$X$ of dimension $\ge C(\varepsilon)\log n$ contains an $n$-point
set $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ such that $1-\varepsilon\le ||x_i-x_j||\le 1+\varepsilon$ for $i\ne j$?

The Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma contains a proof of existence of
such function if the class of Banach spaces is restricted to
finite dimensional Hilbert spaces. The existence of such function
for $\{\ell_p^n\}_{n=1,~1\le p\le\infty}^{\infty}$, was proved
using some basic facts of coding theory by Bartal,
Linial, Mendel, and Naor [Eur. J. Comb.
25, No. 1, 87-92 (2004; Zbl 1042.54020)]

Comment: One approach would be to take $n$ random vectors of norm $c$ for some $c$ depending on the space (like $2^{1/p-1}$ for $l^p$, I think). If the distribution of the distance between two random such vectors is clustered tightly around $1$, you win. So one question to ask is whether this is clustered tightly for all Banach spaces or not.

Comment: @Will Sawin That will work just beautifully in every strictly convex space with known modulus of convexity, so out of all examples mentioned only $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ are nontrivial. However, $\ell^\infty$ is also nice probabilistically (a noticeable portion of coordinates in the difference is nearly maximal by the law of large numbers), so $\ell_1$ looks like the only not totally trivial case among all mentioned so far.

Comment: @fedja (1) No probability is needed for $\ell_\infty$ - just consider $\pm 1$ vectors. (2) I think that you need a uniform bound for the modulus of convexity to get the proof (otherwise you get proof for all finite-dimensional spaces by approximation). (3) There is no such uniform bound for $\ell_p$ as $p\downarrow 1$ or $p\to\infty$.

Comment: Of course, the uniform modulus of continuity is needed here (I wrote "strictly" instead of "uniformly" in hurry, too late to edit now). The simplest example in $\ell_p$ is just the same $\pm 1$ with extra random choice (the large deviations from the mean value for {the sum of the $p$'th powers/number of large values} of the differences are exponentially rare, end of story). What I meant was rather that I cannot come up with any space for which Will's idea would certainly not work and there are plenty of spaces for which it solves the problem in no time. Sorry if that wasn't clear :-).

Comment: Gideon Schechtman turned my attention to the paper of J. Arias-de-Reyna, K. Ball, and R. Villa [Mathematika  45  (1998),  no. 2, 245-252], which contains relevant results and references.

Comment: That's a good one. Unfortunately, the gap between their $\sqrt 2$ and $2$ is still one half of the gap between $1$ and $2$ (which is trivial). Does anyone know if there has been any progress since then that would allow to answer the question as posed? The best I know is the work of Olivier Guedon & Co, which allows one to show an exponential concentration with $\sqrt n$ instead of $n$, i.e., guarantees $m$ points when $\dim X\ge C(\varepsilon)\log^2 m$